# iPhone willResignActive method doesn't complete execution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

My app delegate needs to unlock/lock a purchase order on my microsoft SQL database when it enters the background or terminates.

Here's my code

```
    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"App will enter background");
    if ([purchaseOrderIsLocked boolValue] && [purchaseOrderAutoID intValue] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Unlock Purchase Order because app is in background %i", [purchaseOrderAutoID intValue]);
        [self unlockPurchaseOrderWithAutoID:self.purchaseOrderAutoID];
    }   

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

   NSLog(@"App will enter foreground");

    if ([purchaseOrderIsLocked boolValue] == FALSE && [purchaseOrderAutoID intValue] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Lock Purchase Order because app is coming back %i", [purchaseOrderAutoID intValue]);
        [self lockPurchaseOrderWithAutoID:self.purchaseOrderAutoID];
    }
}

-(void)lockPurchaseOrderWithAutoID:(NSNumber *)autoID {

NSLog(@"lock purchase order called with autoID=%i",[autoID intValue]);

    self.client = [SqlClientConnect connect];
    [self.client executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE PURCHASE SET PURCHASELOCK = '9999' WHERE PURCHASEORDERNO = '%i'", [autoID intValue]] 
          withCompletionBlock:^(SqlClientQuery *query) {

              if (query.succeeded) {
                  NSLog(@"locked purchase order");
                  purchaseOrderIsLocked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
              } else {
                  [self queryFailedWithError:query.errorText]; 
              } 
          }];
}

-(void)unlockPurchaseOrderWithAutoID:(NSNumber *)autoID {
    NSLog(@"unlock purchase order called with autoID=%i",[autoID intValue]);

    self.client = [SqlClientConnect connect];
    [self.client executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE PURCHASE SET PURCHASELOCK = '0' WHERE PURCHASEORDERNO = '%i'", [autoID intValue]] 
          withCompletionBlock:^(SqlClientQuery *query) {

              if (query.succeeded) {
                  NSLog(@"unlocked purchase order");
                  purchaseOrderIsLocked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE];
              } else {
                  [self queryFailedWithError:query.errorText]; 
              } 
          }];
   }

}
```

Okay it looks good to me... however when I run the app this is what I get from the log when I press the home button

```
    2011-12-14 13:41:20.558 MA Mobile[2267:707] App will enter background
    2011-12-14 13:41:20.558 MA Mobile[2267:707] Unlock Purchase Order
     because app is in background 18 

2011-12-14 13:41:20.559 MA Mobile[2267:707] unlock purchase order called with autoID=18
```

It should have gone all the way and posted "unlocked purchase order" but it doesn't
When I resume the app this is what I get.

> 2011-12-14 13:41:44.741 MA Mobile[2267:707] App will enter foreground
>   1 2011-12-14 13:41:44.973 MA Mobile[2267:707] unlocked purchase order

It's like it runs the block code after resuming. Is this related to the block? Should I do something different?

Comment: try adding return; at the end of function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As soon as you pass off the block and return to `-applicationDidResignActive:`, your app is immediately suspended and the asynchronous call you started is essentially paused. You need to let the application know you need to spend more time in the background using [-beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728). You can do it with code like the example below. For more information on long running background tasks, see [Background Execution and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) in the iOS App Programming Guide.

This simple example shows how to use this feature in your code:

```
-(void)unlockPurchaseOrderWithAutoID:(NSNumber *)autoID
{
  NSLog(@"unlock purchase order called with autoID=%i",[autoID intValue]);

  // Start long-running background task
  UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bti = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

  self.client = [SqlClientConnect connect];
  [self.client executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE PURCHASE SET PURCHASELOCK = '0' WHERE PURCHASEORDERNO = '%i'", [autoID intValue]] withCompletionBlock:^(SqlClientQuery *query) {
    if (query.succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"unlocked purchase order");
        purchaseOrderIsLocked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE];
    } else {
        [self queryFailedWithError:query.errorText]; 
    }
    // After we complete the asynchronous block, we need to let the system know we can suspend now
    if( bti != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid )
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bti];
  }];
}
```

Comment: This fixed the issue... just one question. Sometimes this method is being called when we're not entering the background. Is it okay to use the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier always?

Comment: Yes, that won't hurt anything. Also, you need to decide if that's really what you want. For example, you kind of have unbalanced calls now. If you want to unlock only when the app goes into the background, you should use that method `-applicationDidEnterBackgroun:`. If you actually want to unlock whenever the user locks her phone or whatever, then the method you're using is fine but is usually balanced with `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Comment: Super-useful post.  This helps me solved a closing of a shared document when going to background problem I've had ongoing for some time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `applicationWillResignActive` is very fast so it is likely that your task is not finishing before the application loses the foreground. This method is unlike some of the other methods that have similar names. The system is not asking you if it is OK for the application to resign, it is telling you that the application is resigning, now.

Look at the [iOS Developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf) for the section on "Executing a Fininte Length Task in the Background" to see how you can let your task ask for extra time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

`applicationWillResignActive` is informative to tell you that you're app is no longer available to receiving user interaction, such happens when a call is being received or a system alert pops up.

In your case it is because the user hit the home button, so this method is called and then subsequently your app will enter the background which `applicationDidEnterBackground` is then invoked. This is where you want to execute this process, by default though you only have 5 seconds to do what you need to do. In iOS4 however you can request more time, up to 10 minutes by beginning a background task.

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the system by calling [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a). In practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs out your application is terminated and purged from memory.